# 2006 Jeep Grand Cherokee transmission issue

Tags: automatic-transmission, jeep, grand-cherokee

70,000 miles.

Every once in a while when my wife is driving, randomly the "transmission above temp" comes on and the engine revs.  She puts the truck in neutral, shuts the truck off, then back on.  The above temp goes away and the reving stops.  This also happens randomly when she goes to park after a drive.  All fluids are filled, and the trans fluid is not burnt.  The fact that once she turns the truck off and back on, and the temp thing stays off makes me think the transmission is not overheating and it is something else.   Anyone have any ideas, or hear about this before.

Comment: Did you have the code scanned? This forum seems to think it's a faulty PCM (Powertrain Control Module) causing the code. http://www.jeepforum.com/forum/f67/2005-cherokee-transmission-over-temp-1539204/

Comment: The behavior you describe, where the problem goes away when you shut down the car and then restart it suggests that it is something in or related to the TCM (transmission control module). More likely a sensor or something outside of the module since they are more "exposed."

Comment: Before you go chasing ghosts, be sure to eliminate your battery at the reason causing this issue -- just double-check your battery just in case to rule it out before you go dumping money and spending time on a bunch of other items. Have the battery tested for correct charge, have it checked to confirm the amperage rating it what's OEM recommended or greater, and check all the batter cables for tight and snug connections. I'd check and rule this all out first and then look at the PCM or TCM replacement.

Answer (score 1):

Sensor, Bad Ground, PCM reprogramming recall? McDonald's battery & alternator check.  Most of this can't be done by a regular mechanic. Drive it, drive it, drive it right up to a dealer shop tech and see if they can shed some light (while it's occurring) Mine came on intermittently without similar problems and was fixed by a reflash of the PCM(under recall)! Cheers!